# Is it good to implement mixin pattern using #include macro in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, mixins

As we know, mixin is a design pattern to "insert" some behaviors to another class. For example, in Ruby, we can write code like this

```
module Flyable
  def fly
    puts "I'm flying";
  end
end

class Bird
  include Flyable
end
```

C++ does not have language level mixin support, but we can use multiple inheritance to insert code to derived class. But this solution still have it's own problems, like <del>diamond inheritance,</del> unable to override virtual method in interface, unable to access members from "sibling" modules etc.

Later I found I can use #include macro to insert code segment to class definition  to achieve mixin:

```
// in Flyable.h
public:
void fly() {
    // do something ...
}
float flySpeed;
```

And in another file

```
// in Bird.h
class Bird {
#include "Flyable.h"
};
```

So all member variables and functions are inserted to Bird class.

This solution seems to have no obvious drawback. Codes are organized well into different files. Possible name conflicts can be avoided by carefully designed modules without overlapping functions/rules.

But still I afraid there're some problems I haven't seen yet. Is there any problems for this kind of mixin?

---

**Edit**

I know using #include inside class definition is bizarre. But it do solve the problem. And programmers could get used to it if it's really used in the project. So I want to know is there any **practical** reason that we should avoid code like this? Not just it's ugly or bizarre or nobody write like this.

---

**Edit**

I forgot to explain the purpose of the code. Briefly, it's to solve diamond problem without virtual inheritance. As far as I understand, the root cause of diamond problem is abuse of OOP. Bird "is-a" FlyableAnimal, FlyableAnimal "is-a" Animal, Bird "is-a" Carnivore, Carnivore "is-a" Animal. The actual intent of this kind of abuse is code reuse, so instead of "is-a" relationship, "-able" is better. And mixin could bring "-able" relationship.

In C++, mixin can be achieved by multiple inheritance. This is quite good, but it will disable polymorphism. For example, we have Animal interface with pure virtual functions, and we want Bird to implement them. Then we cannot use multiple inheritance to inject the implementation to Bird class. There are some other techniques to achieve this, like composition. But I haven't seen any solution as simple as true mixin. That's the reason why I thought about #include to mixin.

Comment: Mixins for behavior should rarely if ever end up with the diamond-pattern inheritance problem. If you do, then I would argue that your design (or the implementation of it) is flawed.

Comment: As for your "solution", it's really bad from a software engineering point of view. It makes the code harder to read, and hell to maintain.

Comment: Using the pre-processor go generate code is not unheard of. But don't use an include directive. It's idiosyncratic. The eyebrows of other developers will hit the stratosphere when seeing this. A `MAKE_FLYABLE()` macro will be much better in terms of WTF/second.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, using inheritance to mixin will not end up with the diamond-pattern, but still have other problems. I know it seems very bad to use #include, but I cannot say why. Could you explain about it?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, I agree this kind of code is very strange and ugly, but it do solve the problem. So I'd like to know is that the ONLY reason we should avoid code like this?

Comment: It's not just ugly. The macro is ugly too. Ugly is not the problem. Seeing an include directive inside a class definition is like seeing an arm growing out of someones forehead. Bizarre.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, it's bizarre. But is that the only reason? Is there any more practical reason?

Comment: Is the fact cooperation with other people harder not practical enough for you? That's what I meant by this being idiosyncratic.

Comment: @StoryTeller The intent should be very clear. And it is bizarre, but I think programmers could at least get used to it, if it's commonly used in the project. I believe there're many tricks in C++, which might seemed like incorrect usage of language features at the first glance, but treated as patterns and used widely nowadays. For example, template meta programming, SFINAE etc. I don't want to reject a potential pattern just because it's bizarre or misused a language feature.

Comment: @StevenZhao • if that include-in-the-middle were used at my company, the developer would be let go.  So, I recommend using that pattern at my competitor's company.

Comment: Using preprosessor for almost anything except th basic, unavoidable use cases, in C++ is a bad idea, as a rule. This case isn't an exception.

Comment: SFINAE and TMP use language features in ways developers don't expect, but at least somewhat familiar with. They do not use them in ways that go entirely against the grain of what developers know. Seems to me you wish to force its use only due to the emotional attachment inherent in discovering something. You haven't demonstrated value (no, "solves the problem" is not value, since there is an alternative that is less "out there").

Comment: I do not like the solution because it does not achieve anything that isn't achievable in other ways.. <like TMP & SFINAKE>.

What's the point of include a file that define a function? why you cannot achieve it in other way?

Comment: @Ch1v1 Thank you. I added the motivation to the question. Briefly speaking, I want to solve diamond problem without virtual inheritance. And mixin could do that.

Answer (score 2):

> This solution seems to have no obvious drawback.

Drawbacks:

- devs that join your project later will have more to learn before being effective developers in the project. This is obvious only after you have had to maintain other people's non-standard hacks in other projects for a while.
- it is unexpected; this will introduce bugs, cause a lot of delays in development ("hey, I wrote this but it doesn't compile." / "yeah, there is a weird include thing in those file, and you need to write the code like this instead").

> Codes are organized well into different files.

The entire industry applies the following conventions for organizing code:

- everything within a domain, within a single API (whether this means a single class, or a single collection of free functions) and usually within at most two files: one for declarations, one for definitions.
- where feasible, keep things header-only
- where this is not possible, write the implementation in a .impl or _impl class and include it with the header (this is not a de-facto standard, but you see it used with templated code).

Your solution is distinctly different than this (that is, distinctly *not organized well into different files*).

> Possible name conflicts can be avoided by carefully designed modules without overlapping functions/rules.

When people make this distinction ("yes, code is maintainable, you just have to apply extra care"), they imagine that you look at the problem, apply the solution, commit and the problem is solved.

The parts you tend to forget when doing this:

- you will have to make the same decision over and over again, over the lifetime of your project.
- you will have to cause your colleagues to make the same decision, over and over again over the lifetime of your project (including when you are no longer part of it, yourself). This is hard, with a standard solution, let alone with non-standard ones.

> But still I afraid there're some problems I haven't seen yet. Is there any problems for this kind of mixin?

To summarize (tldr):

- you will have an increased constant maintenance effort over the duration of your project.
- this is counter-intuitive for any new hires and increases the cost of others joining your project.
- any devs that follow their intuition / earned experience will expect to see something else in your project (increased WTF/sloc in your code).
- this will cause friction in your team, in the future; at least it will, if you have devs in your team that care about the quality and ease of use of your code.